# Exchange Server Address Resolving to Random String

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange-2013

I am running Exchange 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

When I add my exchange account to Outlook, it seems to work perfectly (sending/receiving email, syncing everything), but when I open the account settings it has the following set as the Server:

ffff9c55-a9e0-47e9-8779-dbf73af18dd7@domain.com

I would have expects this to be: mail.domain.com since this is the DNS A record pointing to the IP of my server.  Where is it getting this server name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the new RPC proxy endpoint. There is more information in this [blog post on the microsoft website](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/01/25/exchange-2013-client-access-server-role.aspx). Just a short quote from the article:

> We no longer use a FQDN for the RPC endpoint. Instead we now use a
>   GUID. The mailbox GUID, to be precise (along with a domain suffix to
>   support multi-tenant scenarios).

There is [another article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/05/23/ambiguous-urls-and-their-effect-on-exchange-2010-to-exchange-2013-migrations.aspx) which might be of interest for you.

Comment: Interesting - I'm reading through the articles (it is just slightly over my head but I am following it for the most part) - so how do they map the GUID to the IP?  Is there some sort of centralized GUID DNS service?

Comment: I think your answer is in the blog post in the section "Outlook Connectivity" after the image. There is no direct mapping to the IP. It is more a mapping to the mailbox store where the mailbox resides. So you need to find out where the mailbox is and then you have the IP.